# Combine a path Optimizer with an Engagement Split activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, path-optimizer

Can I combine a path optimizer containing 2 or more emails with a posterior Engagement Split activity?

I have an scenario where I want to measure how the click/open rate is for a couple of emails. I know I can define the days that will run the experiment and later only the winner will be sent. But on top of that, I want to know if the email has been opened or not after the path optimizer has chosen the winner.

Is there a simple and practical way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Engagement split is not upgraded to work with Path Optimizer yet (as of Dec 2020).

As a workaround is to use 2 Engagement Splits to check for **Opens** of both EDMs separately in journey and then proceed with the flow.

In the example below, Engagement Split 1 checks for EDM 1 is opened or not. Engagement Split 2 checks whether EDM 2 is opened or not. If both EDMs are not opened, they'll receive an SMS (I did a join for both Engagement splits 'Not Opened').

[image]

This is easy to configure if the Path Optimizer has only 2 splits. If there are more splits, then it gets complex to add a cascade of Engagement splits.

Comment: Surely only those who opened EDM1 will be checked against the engagement split for EDM2?

Comment: Updated the image.